# " I am not gonna write a book about it."

Tags: word-usage

Years ago, I watched a video about President Bush (Father). A reporter asked him sth, and he replied " I am not gonna write a book about it. "

Is it an idiom, or his idiom or he just made up some new English sentence?

Comment: Are you referring to when Bush I left office, and he said that he was not going to write his memoirs, which has been a pretty common practice of former presidents.

Comment: No, it was not that time...

Answer (score 3):

The sentence could be either a literal or figurative response to a question. Even if it is figurative, it is not an idiom that I am aware of.

It is a literal response if the reporter asked President Bush if he was going to write a book about something (perhaps a policy decision).

It could also be a figurative response meaning  something like:

*I will say a few things about it, but not many things.*

or

*I have said all I'm going to say about this issue or question.*

etc

Without knowing the context of the question, it is hard to be more specific about the intended meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a reference to an idiom.  People do say "I could write about book about..." meaning that you know a lot about something.  A fun example is from the musical "I Could Write a Book" which featured [a song](http://www.tcm.com/mediaroom/video/198824/Pal-Joey-Movie-Clip-I-Could-Write-a-Book.html) with that same title.